Cannot set property defaults of #<o> which has only a getter on latest version of GrapesJS - grapesjs-lory-slider
Currenty i'm using grapes js v0.21.2. In this version grapesjs-lory-slider plugin throw a uncaught err Cannot set property defaults of # which has only a getter on latest version of GrapesJS. If anyone have any soution please hep me.
I need solution of this problem.
